# Looping of dates

Tags: excel, loops, date, vba

I am trying to loop the dates by having a start date and end date so for example it starts on 3 Apr and ends on 31 Aug. After 3 Apr, it will add 7 days to the date till the end date and display the date and the month. I am trying to loop it but it loop endlessly and does not stop at all. The first two weeks works but starting the Do until loop, it does not work. Thanks in advance for your help

```
x = 5
endD = Sheet1.Range("C20").Value
startD = Sheet1.Range("C19").Value
mth = Month(startD)
Name = MonthName(mth, True)
no = Day(startD)
Sheet1.Range("C2").Value = no
Sheet1.Range("C1").Value = Name
dates = DateAdd("d", 7, startD)
Name = MonthName(Month(dates), True)
Sheet1.Range("D2").Value = Name
Sheet1.Range("D1").Value = Day(dates)
W = dates
Do Until W = endD
m = DateAdd("d", 7, W)
W = m
no = 0
Name = " "
no = Day(m)
Name = MonthName(Month(m), True)
Sheet1.Cells(1, x).Value = Name
Sheet1.Cells(2, x).Value = no
x = x + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

> `Do Until W = endD`

Ths could result in endless loop because your incremented value of the variable `W` may *"jump"* over the endD. Replace it by:

```
Do Until W >= endD
```

Comment: Now that we solved the endless loop problem, try some `Debug.Print endD`, check your variables in the debugger, etc. @RachelChia

Comment: it's very weird cause it can work when end date is 31 Jul but not other dates

Comment: @RachelChia probably the format of your dates is not compatible with what Excel expects. Again try to put `Debug.Print endD` before your loop and look what it displays in the *immediate window*.

Comment: i realise the end date must be a monday , an exact date for the loop to work

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date

FirstDate = Range("startdate").Value
LastDate = Range("enddate").Value

NextDate = FirstDate
Range("tripdays").Select

Do Until NextDate > LastDate

    ActiveCell.Value = NextDate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    NextDate = NextDate + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

hows this?

Comment: Nope this not what I want. i want it to loop every week from start date to end date and display the date and month